# Is there an alternative to MyWOT ("Web of Trust")?

Tags: web-apps, web-browser, security, web-services

As you hopefully know the NDR (a German TV station) disclosed that [WOT Services sells the complete browser history](https://thehackernews.com/2016/11/web-of-trust-addon.html) and additional data ([the technical information [German]](https://www.kuketz-blog.de/wot-addon-wie-ein-browser-addon-seine-nutzer-ausspaeht/)) of its users without any anonymisation, although they claim in their [privacy policy](https://www.mywot.com/en/privacy/privacy_policy) to just collect and sell anonymised information.

---

**Is there an alternative platform for reputation of websites/domains**, as dedicated software, browser add-on, web-app, simple website or maybe just a database? - For now everything is welcome.

The ratings should be done by the community or crowd-based, just by company(/ies) won't be very trustworthy, but if anyhow possible as transparent as possible in the opposite to WOT.

I don't think a real [WoT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_of_trust) for websites/domains (as for OpenPGP) exists or is even possible?

Answer (score 1):

### Update:

added one additional service and changed formatting to make a clearer difference between the reputation-sites and obviously only/mainly malware-scanning...

---

### [URLVoid](http://www.urlvoid.com/)

URLVoid looks like a "meta-engine"; it scores sites based on a [bunch of other services](http://www.urlvoid.com/about-us/). it provides links to all individual results and displays some additional information like ip-address, location, hoster, etc.

- it is just a **web-service**, so no software is available but they provide a **experimental [API](http://www.urlvoid.com/api/)** to query URLVoid database.
- the ratings are done by the individual services and it seems that they are mainly companies (maybe some of them with community-contribution and/or transparent scoring or even not).

---

### [TrustScam](https://trustscam.com/)

although about itself there is very [few information and just is spanish](https://trustscam.com/legal), it looks interesting and nice polished to me. it works up some different information from sources like WOT, MozRank, Alexa and displays them beside whois- & certificate-information.

- as far as is see it is only a **website**.
- the rating comes obviously **at least partly from MyWOT**, but they also give the ability to send your **own reviews** with thumb up/down and a comment.

---

<sub>[Norton Safe Web](https://safeweb.norton.com/)</sub>

<sub>it looks like Norton Safe Web only scans for viruses but no really further information is given.</sub>

- <sub>a dedicated software just for ratings is not available, it is **just a website**.</sub>
- <sub>there is no information how the scoring is done, but **additionally** a **community rating** with the number of users who rated is displayed.</sub>

---

<sub>[McAfee SiteAdvisor](https://www.siteadvisor.com/)</sub>

<sub>McAfee SiteAdvisor [checks for various dangers](http://www.siteadvisor.com/howitworks/index.html) like downloads, links, phishing, spam, etc.</sub>

- <sub>beside the **website** it seams that there is also at least a **windows-software**.</sub>
- <sub>the scoring is entirely done by the company.</sub>